# DNS Suffix Search list does not work when Group Policy applies the "DNS Suffix Search List"

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a DNS Suffix Search list applied through Group Policy in an AD Domain with Windows 2012 server. When the DNS Suffix Search list is applied with Group Policy to the computers of a domain - those computers cannot ping a single qualified hostname and have it append the fqdn. As soon as the Group Policy is blocked - by doing block inheritance and the same DNS Suffix search list is manually input on the Network Adapter under  DNS --> Append These DNS Suffix (in order); then it works - which is the same place the GPO puts those suffix.

In Linux it works great and it works in windows but only when done manually. Please help - I know this Group Policy setting is meant to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following the description of your problem - for example - With GPO in place and suffix search contains "corp.acme.com" and/or "acme.com", lookup for "roadrunner.corp" fails while "roadrunner" succeeds?

Modify your GPO to also contain the following setting:
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Network / DNS Client / `Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries` = `Enabled`

There a long explanation with more examples in the MMC help text for this policy setting.